# Executing a PHP script using objective-c

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to execute a PHP script which increments a field in a database. I have the script working and I am currently modifying the database perfectly using ASIHTTPRequest, but I feel as though I should be using a different method given that I do not need a return.

Is this what's called an HTTP POST?

```
    incrementOrDecrementURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://myURL/doScript.php"];

NSURL *requestURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:incrementOrDecrementURL];

//The actual request
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];
// Becoming the request delegate
//To get callbacks like requestFinished: or requestFailed:
[request setDelegate:self];    

// Start request
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form the [docs: Sending a form POST with ASIFormDataRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest)

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

But also note, that ASIHTTPRequest is not [maintained anymore by it's original author.](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D)

Comment: so, should I transfer to a different API? If so, which would you recommend? Thanks.

Comment: the post I linked has some recommendations. I am using AFNetworking now.

Answer (score 0):

`ASIHTTPRequest` by default sends a GET request, not POST. It's proper that GETs don't update anything at the server, so you should use a POST: `[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"]`. You can just have your `doScript.php` return an HTTP 204 No Content response. PHP [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function. But it's good design to return at least some sort of protocol-specific status code regarding what actually happened at the server. I often just return a simple JSON response such as `{"status":"OK"}`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a oneway request, not a POST.

But, you should never update any database with a GET request, so you should use a POST.

One way to do this is to immediately return a response, and then update the database, but the better approach, since this library is no longer maintained (http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) you may want to use NSUrlConnection and just ignore the response, and go on.

Comment: @James.Black Coming back to your approcah with the NSURLConnection...do you think this is feasible? I basically want the user to be able to press a button and have this script executed in the background.....

Comment: @derek.lo - Yes, you can do this in the background. Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728631/asynchronous-request-to-the-server-from-background-thread