# Completion handler not being called when containing function is within a while loop

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

```
while ( /* Some condition that will not be met in this example */ ) {
    if( shouldSendRequest ) {
        [launchpad getRequestToken];
    } 
    else {
        // Next step
    }
}

- (void)getRequestToken {

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
         completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

         [self requestForRequestTokenDidComplete:data withResponse:response withError:error];
     }];
}

-(void)requestForRequestTokenDidComplete:(NSData *)data 
       withResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response withError:(NSError *)error {
    // Deal with the returned token
}
```

The problem I have is that the completion handler in `getRequestToken` is never being called as long as `getRequestToken` is inside the while loop. As soon as I comment out the while loop, everything works.

What's happening here and is it possible to prevent it? I has planned to use the while loop to prevent the flow of execution moving on before this (and other) completion handlers had finished doing their thing.

Comment: How would it prevent flow from moving on; wouldn't it repeatedly re-send the request?

Comment: There's more to the code than what I've shown here. I've updated the snippet to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: If you want to wait for response in this thread why using asynchronous request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because `NSURLConnection` works along with the runloop to perform the async request.  Therefore if you *stop* the runloop by halting flow within the `while` statement you are preventing the request from completing.

You will need to artificially pump the runloop or use a background thread.

See:

- [Asynchronous request to the server from background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728631/asynchronous-request-to-the-server-from-background-thread)
- [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: making multiple requests in a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409211/nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousrequestqueuecompletionhandler-making-multiple)
- [GCD and async NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918501/gcd-and-async-nsurlconnection)

And lots of others...

Comment: Don't artificially pump anything;  `while(...)` style polling loops are very much to be avoided.